# backbone.js changing el value of views before render is called

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, render, el

I have 3 different views, each of which share this same el value:

```
el:"<div id='main-inner'>"
```

and in the render function:

```
this.$el.html(html);
```

I was asked to combine all of these onto one page, so I'm trying to make a master view that has a collection of these views and renders each of the views within it.  The problem is they each write to the same element, #main-inner and clear it's html before appending it's own html value.  What is the proper way to change the el value before rendering from the master/wrapper view?  Is this the best way to go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Make each view create its own `<div>` and put that inside `#main-inner`, then call `view.remove()` to clean up the old view before adding the new one.

Comment: can you show me an example of that? and I don't understand why call view.remove()?

Comment: before displaying the next,  call `close` function for the previous and  bind following function 
`close: function() {
       this.stopListening();
       this.$el.empty();
    }`

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich: Why add a `close` when there is already a [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) that can be overridden if you want to `$el.empty()` rather than `$el.remove()`?

Comment: @muistooshort, I wanted to say that, use `this.$el.empty()`, not `this.$el.remove();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hand over the el to the view when you initialize your views:

```
var view1 = new myView({el:'#div1'});
var view2 = new myView({el:'#div2'});
var view3 = new myView({el:'#div3'});
```

And in your view:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

   initialize: function(options){
     this.el = options.el; 
   }

});
```

Now you have Views, each rendering in it's own el.

Hope this can help.

Comment: your initializer is redundant in this case.

Comment: I tried to inject the el value that way in this example http://jsfiddle.net/TFtLL/8/ but it's not working :/

Answer (score -1):

You can define your el as global and use it.
example:

App.Common.el = "";

use :

App.Common.el